# php error on basic php

Tags: php

Im trying to do the following but keep getting a error.

```
<?php
echo '<a href="'javascript:toggle5'" id.'imageDivLink'('profilebar', 'imageDivLink');">' .$USER->firstname.' '.$USER->lastname.'</a>';
?>
```

Comment: what exact errors do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code contains a multitude of PHP, JavaScript and HTML errors. The following is what I assume you meant by it all.

```
<?php
echo '<a href="javascript:toggle5()" id="'
    . imageDivLink('profilebar', 'imageDivLink') . '">'
    . $USER->firstname . ' ' . $USER->lastname
    . '</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<a href="javascript:toggle5()" id="'.imageDivLink('profilebar','imageDivLink').'">'.$USER->firstname.' '.$USER->lastname.'</a>';
```

Comment: Since you edited your answer, the first line no longer makes much sense. (P.S. missing semicolon at the end, I'm afraid I lack the privileges to edit.)